# Email Unique Validation with Joi Library in node js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, joi

I want to use joi library to validate email as well as to check if it is exist or not. means i want to check email is unique or not. How to do that. I want to use mongoose model to apply query in joi library to check email is exist or not in user table.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the database isn't Joi's area of responsibility. But if you still want to use it, you can check the details in the [release document of v16](https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2037)

Joi v16 provides `external()` method to do an external async validation. It can be used for a database lookup.

```
const lookup = async (id) => {

    const user = await db.get('user', id);
    if (!user) {
        throw new Error('Invalid user id');
    }
};

const schema = Joi.string().external(lookup);
await schema.validateAsync('1234abcd');
```